# Customise partition assignor for groupBy

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to customise partition assignment for a Ktable statestore changelog (groupBy/reduce)? Usage is to group all order-item events (by order ID and item no.) for an order in one partition.

Currently changelog topic is partitioned by its key, so order-item messages for one order can reside in different partition.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions are determined by key, as you've said. So, use `map` operator to change the key to combination of "order ID and item no"

Comment: Yes I need to change the key to do the aggregation.  But is there a way to control the partition assignment on the rekeyed change log topic?  Such that all itemised state for an order can go to the same partition?

Comment: Not that I know of. That's what `map` already is doing; giving a new key, which is computed into a partition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the partitioning for changelog topics. It's hard-coded and does not use a `Partitioner` to begin with.

If you have an input topic (or repartition topic via `groupBy`), a record from input partition X will map to task X (ie, state store shard X), and use changelog topic partition X.

We need to have this 1:1:1:1 mapping to guarantee correctness. If input topic partitions (and task) X are re-assigned to a different instance, we can recover the state by reading partition X from the changelog topic.